# Singleton method and class method Java

Tags: java

I'm wondering what different between static method and singleton class method when i use them for multiple thread. I think if use static method, it will conflict result data or parameter but i don't think use singleton method class then the same problem will occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a static method it can be used without creating an instance of the class, which is not true when you're creating a class-method.

Synchronization is orthogonal issue: you'll probably have to use some kind of synchronization mechanism regardless of which one of the two options you chose to use.

Comment: Thanks you answer! I create ProfileUtils  class has all static method then I use ProfileUtils's method for multiple thread. In the scenario, i can use Singleton pattern for ProfileUtils class

Answer (score 1):

We use "synchronized" to solve the multiple threads problem.
The static method and singleton method's main differences are:
1. a static method can only use the static fields and methods, as a non-static method can use all fields and methods of the class.
2. a static method can be called without a instance, as a non-static method must be called by a instance.

Comment: I had used synchronized for static method but it not good solve for problem, because that will dead lock method while multiple  thread. Whether what solutions better it ? Thanks you so much.

Comment: I'm not familiar with multiple thread too. Sorry for can't help you.